# How to force to download a file than view inside the browser depending on the user agent via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, header

On my (drupal) website I have a pdf which can be viewed/ downloaded.

```
http://www.mysite.de/assets/thefile.pdf
```

Firefox is also capable of viewing pdfs inside the browser rather than downloading it. The problem is that the pdf viewer is buggy as hell, at least for our < win7 users.

I am not that familiar with .htaccess, but I guess it is possible to set a file header which tells the browser to download a file. But how can I do that conditionally depending on the user agent?

As far as I have found out, the targeted user agent is `/.*(windows nt 5\.1).*(firefox).*/i` (firefox on win xp and lower, probably).

edit: i know i can force file to be downloaded like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

but not how to add another condition, i.e. the user agent.

Comment: You could do this using mod_rewrite - a `RewriteCond` to check the user agent, and then a `RewriteRule` that uses the `T` flag to send a Content-Type header that forces the download dialog.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force download for specific file extensions, the easiest way is using [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) which is a [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) directive.
For pdf, you can add this line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

The key is `octet-stream`, this is the guy forcing download (and disallowing "Open..." items in download popups for browsers).

Hope this helps!

**EDIT (asker's request in comment)**
As I got to go I try to give as much details as possible.
If you mean to add a user agent 'prevention' you need these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^UserAgentNameHere [OR]
(...more user agents...then last one:....)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AnotherUserAgentsName
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

If you mean  e.g. "forcing download for different browsers only", you need Apache Server v2.4 as you'll need support for [Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html). And in this case you can do this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == '.*MSIE.*'">
    AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
</If>
```

If you meant something else, please specify (would also be great if you could post another question instead of updating/changing/commenting this one which is related to something else)

Comment: thanks very much! could you add how i can apply this rule for one specific user agent? thanks

Comment: what user agent you mean? "bad bots", client's browser / browser-version or OS? much more info is needed for that

Comment: well just read my question and you have the much more info :)

Comment: mark, thank you for your effort but it seems you did not read my full question (i guess so because you refer your edit to my "comment", although my question is clear in the first place).
please provide me the full code block for the following logical conditions:
if the file to be downloaded == '...myfile.pdf' and the useragent matches the following regex: 'my regex' then force the file to be downloaded (octet stream). thank you very much

Comment: @Alex that's the 2nd part "<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == '.*MSIE.*'">". Server can have a "default behavior" only for file types but not for specific file names.

Comment: @Alex i think this answer should be marked as correct answer !